# Clone/Duplicate/Copy an Existing Application Pool in IIS 7

Tags: c#, iis

In PowerShell one can clone an existing IIS 7 application pool to a new application pool, retaining all the source pools settings in the new pool.  Like this...

```
import-module webadministration
copy IIS:\AppPools\AppPoolTemplate IIS:\AppPools\NewAppPool -force
```

Now I would like to do the same thing in C# using the classes in the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace.  I have browsed the namespace and I cannot find a way to do this easily.  There is the MemberwiseClone method that I could call to create a shallow copy of the existing app pool, but I don't know if that would duplicate all the original app pools properties.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Comment: @Dan Maguire, sorry no, not exactly.  The one answer I received so far doesn't fully solve the problem.  It doesn't address how to get the properties from the AppPool in the first section to the newly created pool in the second section.  At the moment I am considering calling the PowerShell code directly inside my C# program.  I have a couple weeks left before the deadline to solve this.  I will post whatever solution I choose once I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found only one way so far to copy an application pool in C#:

```
    private void creationizeAppPoolOldSchool(string strFullName)
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create(); 
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration); 
        runspace.Open(); 
        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
        scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
        scriptInvoker.Invoke("import-module webadministration");
        string str = "copy IIS:\\AppPools\\_JANGO_FETT IIS:\\AppPools\\" + strFullName + " –force";
        scriptInvoker.Invoke(str);
    }
```

Because my real need is to have a set of predefined settings on all new application pools, I actually abandoned copying an existing template pool and instead create an application pool with predefined settings using `Microsoft.Web.Administration`.  Although that's not the original question, I share it anyway because someone browsing this post may also be interested in it:

```
    public static void CreateCoCPITAppPool(string strName)
    {
        using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            ApplicationPool newPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add(strName);
            newPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";
            newPool.AutoStart = true;
            newPool.ProcessModel.UserName = "username";
            newPool.ProcessModel.Password = "password";
            newPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
            newPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time = TimeSpan.Zero;
            newPool.ProcessModel.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10000); // .Zero;
            newPool.ProcessModel.ShutdownTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
            newPool.Failure.RapidFailProtection = false;
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
            IDictionary<string, string> attr = newPool.Recycling.RawAttributes;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in attr)
            {
                // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " = " + entry.Value);
            }
            ConfigurationAttributeCollection coll = newPool.Recycling.Attributes;
            foreach (ConfigurationAttribute x in coll)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Name + " = " + x.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a copy method, but you could access the current app pool's properties and then create a new app pool with the same properties:

```
// How to access a specific app pool
DirectoryEntry appPools = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + serverName + "/w3svc/apppools", adminUsername, adminPassword);
foreach (DirectoryEntry AppPool in appPools.Children)
{
    if (appPoolName.Equals(AppPool.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // access the properties of AppPool...
    }
}
```

Then you create a new pool in your code by calling the method listed below:

```
CreateAppPool("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools", "MyAppPool");
```

App pool creation method from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525598%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
static void CreateAppPool(string metabasePath, string appPoolName)
{
    //  metabasePath is of the form "IIS://<servername>/W3SVC/AppPools"
    //    for example "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools" 
    //  appPoolName is of the form "<name>", for example, "MyAppPool"
    Console.WriteLine("\nCreating application pool named {0}/{1}:", metabasePath, appPoolName);

    try
    {
        if (metabasePath.EndsWith("/W3SVC/AppPools"))
        {
            DirectoryEntry apppools = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath);
            DirectoryEntry newpool = apppools.Children.Add(appPoolName, "IIsApplicationPool");
            newpool.CommitChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Failed in CreateAppPool; application pools can only be created in the */W3SVC/AppPools node.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed in CreateAppPool with the following exception: \n{0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```